# How do I find out where .aspx page is pulling its header?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I haven't worked with C# or ASP.NET before, but I'm trying to update some .aspx pages on a site. I'm noticing that there are also some updates that also need to be made in the `<head>` when I look at the source of the page, but I don't know how to determine where that header info is being pulled from to make that change.

Here are the two lines I'm seeing before it jumps into the HTML content:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="DefaultLogin.aspx.vb" Inherits="TIMSSSSO.Web.DefaultLogin" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="Generic.Foundation.WebControls" Assembly="Generic.Foundation.WebControls" %>
```

Does any of this tell me where I should go to edit the header? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the code-behind for the page?  It's quite possible the header is being set there.  And you're working with VB.NET, not C# (`<%@ Page Language="vb"....` - C# would be "cs").

Comment: That's the VB file? No, unfortunately not. Thanks for clarifying the language

Comment: Yes, the code-behind (the VB file) may very well be setting the header, so without that file you're out of luck.  :(

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aren't there any other references to "include files" in the form of master pages (using `@ Master`), user controls (with  `@ register`), etc?